# Convert numeric data from database

Tags: vb.net

In my system default decimal separator is comma.
In database I have written numeric values as strings but in format with decimal separator point.
Now, when I read data from database like this "3.2" with following code I get value 32D!

```
NumericUpDown1.Value = CDec(reader("myfield"))
```

Is here any way that I can get decimal value of 3,2 from showed code in described situation?

Comment: Just to satisfy your requirements: `reader("myfield").ToString().Replace(".", ",")`. But really correct solution for your problem is change database type to the `Decimal`. And you stop facing format problems.

Comment: Another solution: `Decimal.Parse(reader("myfield"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` InvarianCulture have decimal separator a dot.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks. It works with invariant culture. It is anyway needed to convert reader to string first: Decimal.Parse(CStr(reader("myfield")), ic). Unfortunately I can't change datatypes in this database, it is not mine.

Comment: I think `reader("myfield").ToString()` will do same things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know your number is stored as a string in the format "1,23456". You are dealing with a globalization issue, and as such, you could convert the string using the appropriate culture formatting settings.

`NumericUpDown.Value` is of type `Decimal`, so I use the function `Convert.ToDecimal`.

For this example, I'll assume the number being inserted was stored in the database by a Croatian, so I'd use "hr-HR" for the culture name.

```
Dim myFieldCroatia As String = "1,2345678901234567890123456789"
NumericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(myFieldCroatia, New Globalization.CultureInfo("hr-HR"))
```

And if it were stored by an American, I'd use "en-US"

```
Dim myFieldUnitedStates As String = "1.2345678901234567890123456789"
NumericUpDown2.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(myFieldUnitedStates, New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

As an aside, if you had first converted to Double, and implicitly converted to Decimal, you would have lost any precision past 15 to 17 decimal places. Not sure if it's required, but it's worthy of noting.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx) for a complete list of culture names

Comment: Thanks Verdolino. Your answer have most sense. And I have Option Strict always turned on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  NumericUpDown1.Value  = CDec(reader("myfield"), new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
```

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: This do not work as is showed. First is needed to convert reader value to string. Or I miss something? Anywaj, I get an error unless I specify a NumberFormatInfo.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDouble(reader("myfield").ToString().Replace("," , "."))
```

is another way if you don't want to convert to Double then you could use ToDecimal.

Comment: `NumericUpDown1.Value` is a Decimal.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I wouldn't use the `CDec` but the `Val` function instead.
Try this code :

```
NumericUpDown1.Value = Val(reader("myfield").ToString().Replace("," , "."))
```

Comment: Because of cleaning my code I don't use Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace and I think Val is declared there. Again, in this procedure you also convert number to string first then convert it back to number.

Comment: Why? **1.)** `NumericUpDown.Value` is `Decimal`, so why would you use `Val` which returns a `Double`? **2.)** This would fail with `Option Strict On`, in which case you would wrap this in `CDec` anyway. **3.)** `CDec(reader("myfield").ToString().Replace("," , "."))` works the same with a properly formatted input.

Comment: Verdolino: what a mess in your comment... 1) decimal objects can be converted to decimal 2) what would you need `Strict on` for? 3) I'd to developed applications to foreign countries and I saw that the separator to decimal for IsNumeric and CDec functions depended to Windows settings, in my case, CDec("1,1") returns 1,1 but CDec("1.1") returns an exception. For the Val function, the separator is always a dor

Comment: [Val() returns Integer or Double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) but you are assigning it to a Decimal. "decimal objects can be converted to decimal"... but it's not a decimal, it's a String, then a Double, then an implicit conversion to Decimal. `Option Strict On` points out implicit conversions (this wouldn't even be allowed in C# without a cast, by the way), which are very common among vb programmers and *allow* for mistakes. Even if you use `Val`, you should not replace `CDec` but perhaps use both.

Comment: I meant a double can be converted to decimal, that's possible with the Convert.ToDecimal function but here in this context, it's not required as the conversion can easily be done. And still, never put  `Option Strict on`, don't even try to put restrictions in a program, it's a good way to make you waste your time to find out the solution, and still, `CDec` has to be prohibited (explained earlier)